# Mysql GROUP_CONCAT issue with same dates and hours

Tags: mysql

I trying to make an query to concat some records and i'm not getting the results expected.
The scenario is the following:
A teacher can shedule (visits, workshop) outside school and can bring several classes.
The database allow to insert each classes as unique record, so now i want to use the group_concat to show to users, only one record with x classes.
This is an example of my DB:

```
id ,activity      ,location              ,date      ,hour , class
344,Vou ao teatro!,Teatro                ,2021-03-26,11:00, A
345,Vou ao teatro!,Teatro                ,2021-03-26,11:00, B
346,Vou ao teatro!,Teatro                ,2021-03-26,11:00, C
347,Museu         ,Praça da República - V,2021-05-06,10:00, D
348,Museu         ,Praça da República - V,2021-05-06,10:00, E
350,Museu         ,Praça da República - V,2021-05-06,10:00, F
354,Museu         ,Praça da República - V,2021-05-06,10:00, G
355,Museu         ,Praça da República - V,2021-05-06,10:00, H
```

So what i need is to concat id(first element) and class(last element) to have only 2 lines instead of 9

What i have so far is this:

```
SELECT ae.Atividade, ae.Local, ae.DataAula, TIME_FORMAT(ae.HoraInicio, '%H:%i') AS HoraInicio,
       TIME_FORMAT(ae.HoraFim, '%H:%i') AS HoraFim, ae.Autorizado, p.Nome,
       GROUP_CONCAT(ae.idAula order by ae.idAula) AS idAula,
       GROUP_CONCAT(t.Turma order by t.Turma) AS turma
FROM
    aulaexteriorturmas AS a
        INNER JOIN aulaexterior AS ae
                   ON (a.idAula = ae.idAula)
        INNER JOIN turmas AS t
                   ON (a.idTurma = t.idTurma)
        INNER JOIN anosescolares AS aescolar ON (ae.idAnoEscolar = aescolar.idAnoEscolar)
        INNER JOIN professores AS p on (ae.idProfessor = p.idProfessor)
WHERE aescolar.Estado = 1 and ae.Autorizado = '-1'
group BY ae.DataAula, p.Nome;
```

The result is something like this (showing first line)

```
**346,346,346**, Vou ao teatro!,Teatro 2021-03-26,11:00,12:30,"A,B,C"
```

The id is repeated...so wrong

Any help please?

Comment: `GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT column)`.

Comment: Thanks, working better.